# uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,not/1),play/0)

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to understand this [code](https://web.archive.org/web/20181005004256/http://wdok.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/studium-und-lehre/selbststudium/pgp/slides/ticTacToeCompleteForStudents.pl/view) for tic tac toe in prolog.
I'm able to compile the code in gprolog,

```
| ?- ['/**/**/**/tictactoe.pl'].
    compiling /**/**/**/tictactoe.pl for byte code...
    /**/**/**/tictactoe.pl compiled, 142 lines read - 11825 bytes written, 12 ms
    (2 ms) yes
```

but when I'm executing `play`, I'm getting the following error:

```
| ?- play.
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,not/1),play/0)
```

As you can see in the last line of the code, `play` is defined as follows :

```
play :-not(clear), repeat, getmove, makemove, printboard, done.
```

And the same code is working perfectly fine in `SWI-prolog`

When I'm trying to run the prolog file in terminal with either of the following 2 commands

```
gplc --no-top-level tictactoe.pl
```

or

```
gplc  tictactoe.pl
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "predicate(assert/1)", referenced from:
      predicate(getmove/0) in gplcMtKfGg.o
      predicate(makemove/0) in gplcMtKfGg.o
  "predicate(not/1)", referenced from:
      predicate(empty/1) in gplcMtKfGg.o
      predicate(different/2) in gplcMtKfGg.o
      predicate(play/0) in gplcMtKfGg.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
compilation failed
```

Comment: Read the documentation. Maybe there is no `not/1` in GNU-Prolog. You should probably use `\+ clear` instead of `not(clear)`. If you read the SWI-Prolog documentation on `not/1`, you might find that "True if Goal cannot be proven. Retained for compatibility only. New code should use `\+/1`."

Comment: PS: same goes for `assert`. It should be `asserta` or `assertz`. But just go ahead and read the documentation.

Comment: It's working correctly after I replaced `not` with `\+` and `assert` with `asserta`. Thanks @Boris

Comment: Not sure if it should be `asserta` or `assertz`. You should read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `assert` with `asserta` solved the problem.